# How to get a string after and before a specific substring in Python?

Tags: python, string, substring

How can I get a string after and before a specific substring?

For example, I want to get the strings before and after `:` in

```
my_string="str1:str2"
```

(which in this case it is: `str1` and `str2`).

Comment: `my_string.split(':')`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case you may want different things, but this might work best for you:

```
lst = my_string.split(":")
```

Then, lst will be: `['str1', 'str2']`

You can also find the index of the substring by doing something like:

```
substring = ":"
index = my_string.find(":")
```

Then split the string on that index:

```
first_string = my_string[:index]
second_string = my_string[index+len(substring):]
```